# How to setup multiple has_many through relationships in Rails3 dependent on field in joining table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

This is probably really simple, but I'm still sorta beginning rails and can't seem to figure out the right phrase to type into Google to find the answer.

I've got a pretty simple has_many through relationship described below:

User
-user_id
-name

Article
- article_id
- title

Article_Relationship
- user_id
- article_id
- relationship_type

On the relationship type, it would be a string or int to represent a type of relations, so like favorite, recently_viewed, written_by, ect.  How to a setup the multiple has_many :articles, :through => :article_relationships so I can easily access the articles of a specific type of relationship through something like user.recently_viewed, user.favorite, ect?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track but you just need to make use of scopes:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Here RECENTLY_VIEWED_TYPE refers to the type of relationship, whatever
  # that constant is defined as.
  scope :recently_viewed,
    where('article_relationships.relationship_type=?', RECENTLY_VIEWED_TYPE)
end
```

Then you can access this from the User directly:

```
@user.articles.recently_viewed.all
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `:conditions` into `has_many` along with your `:through` option. You can also name the association something different. So that gives you the ability to do something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :article_relationships
  has_many :articles, :through => :article_relationships

  has_many :recently_viewed_articles, :class_name => 'Article', :through => :article_relationships, :conditions => ['article_relationships.relationship_type = ?', 1]

  has_many :favorite_articles, :class_name => 'Article', :through => :article_relationships, :conditions => ['article_relationships.relationship_type = ?', 2]
end
```

You might have to play with the options passed to `has_many` a little bit, but you get the idea.

Comment: That seemed to work well! Thanks!
I had to add in :source => 'article' in addition to the rest of has_many options or it didn't know what I was referring too, but once that was done, it was smooth sailing!